# how do I determine which image is the featured image in the database

Tags: database, post-thumbnails

I've queried all children of the post, and two records are shown. This is ok because there are 2 images in the gallery, but I can see no field in the database which makes it clear which one is the featured image.

I have joined the wp_postmeta table also, but there is no meta_key which indicates which of the 2 is the featured image.

Note: I do not want to look in the admin panel, I need a programmatic way to determine from the current database setup.

**Does anyone know how the system knows which is the featured image in the db?**

Comment: Look at [how `get_post_thumbnail_id()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.2.1/wp-includes/post-thumbnail-template.php#L25) pulls data on post thumbnails, that should give you some clues..

Comment: This is the solution - apparently there is a record in the postmeta table which registers the thumbnail ID against the post id, so post_id = 'XX' and meta_key is '_thumbnail_id'

Answer (score 5):

this comes down to a simple one line and there is no need to get all of the children using:

```
$featured image_id = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_thumbnail_id', true );
```

Comment: Why not just use [get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID )](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_thumbnail_id)?

Comment: @Chip: You could, its basically a wrapper for the `get_post_meta` i  posted with validation  for the post id. If you look at the code [here](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.2.1/wp-includes/post-thumbnail-template.php#L25) you will see that its the same.

Comment: true, but I think it might be a bit easier to understand. :) In any case, +1 for the one-line-of-code solution!

Comment: My question was asking where is this listed in the database. As such the first answer gave me the solution

Comment: its listed in the postmeta table under meta_key named `_thumbnail_id` for each post